# How to keep linearGradient position where the animate stopped

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas, svg-animate

Is there any option to keep the gradient position where the animation finished ?

```html
<svg id="battery" width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
      <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
      id="loading-frame" fill="url(#loading)"></path>
      <linearGradient id="loading" x1="0">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#eaeaea"></stop>
        <animate attributeName="x1" dur="3s" from="-100%" to="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify an additional attribute for `animate`:

`fill="freeze"`

```html
<svg id="battery" width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
      <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
      id="loading-frame" fill="url(#loading)"></path>
      <linearGradient id="loading" x1="0">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff0000"></stop>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#eaeaea"></stop>
        <animate attributeName="x1" fill="freeze" dur="3s" from="-100%" to="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```